# Scope of const reference to a template in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I read unique_ptr implementation in STL and have some questions. The code of `unique_ptr::swap()` is below:

```
void
swap(unique_ptr& __u)
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(_M_t, __u._M_t);
}
```

I have two questions for the function:

1. `unique_ptr::_M_t` is a private member, why can `__u._M_t` be accessed?
2. Why template arguments are not specified in `unique_ptr& __u`? Is this done by a specific unique_ptr's constructor?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The function is a member.  It is allowed to access private members of any instance.
2. If it's defined in the class body, the template arguments are not necessary.  The compiler assumes the same arguments that the template was instantiated with.  You would need arguments if you wanted to refer to a different template instantiation, for example, if the code for `unique_ptr<int>` for some reason needed to refer to `unique_ptr<double>`, it would need to be explicit.

Comment: 3. A member function is allowed to access private members of any instance of its own class. If you used explicit template arguments to refer to another specialization (instantiation), you would get a different class, and no access to private members.